# Formula to this pattern? $1$, $11$, $21$, $1211$, $111221$, $\ldots$

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

I have this pattern:

```
1
11
21
1211
111221
```

I'm guessing it's a fibo pattern, been at it for hours now. Anyone know?

Comment: I know where it comes from - each line is what you get when you speak the previous line - one one; two ones; one two, one one; etc.

Comment: Hint: Not Fibonacci. Read the digits out loud to find the pattern.

Comment: So next would be: 312211

Comment: You could also check out http://oeis.org/A005150

Comment: A semi-interesting note about this sequence is that you will never get a number greater than $3$.

Comment: @Vincent Well, yeah.  You can never reach some $\dots1111\dots$ , as that would've simplified from the previous number down to $\dots21\dots$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's known as the [look-and-say](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) sequence.

Answer (score 2):

In the first row, there is one 1 (11). In the second, two 1s (21). In the third, there is one 2 then one 1 (1211). In the fourth, there is one 1 then one 2 then two 1s (111221). It continues in this way, so the next row would be 312211.